# In react native, how can I make the keyboard show a key to "collapse" or "minimize" keyboard?

Tags: react-native, mobile, keyboard, expo

I know using `Keyboard.dismiss()` can make the keyboard disappear, but I specifically want to know if there is a way to add a key on the keyboard (like a minimize key, a downward triangle etc) for dimissing it? It is intended for users to see visually instead of having to try to click a white space (where I implemented `Keyboard.dismiss()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use the prop [keyboardType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#keyboardtype) correctly you're gonna get what you want. Take a look [here](https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/) with more details in what which value that can be putted in this prop does.

Comment: Thanks. The desired "minimize" or "collapse" key doesn't seem to be in any option there.

Comment: Do you have a photo of the "minimize" or "collapse" key you desire? Because, as far I as I know, the "minimize" or "collapse" key is the blue button that is appearing [here](https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/) in the keyboard photos and in the iOS is the "return" button.